# Why the escape sequence \b producing a dot as the output in jdoodle?

Tags: java, unicode-escapes

I am trying to demonstrate the \b escape function in java, but the output is a dot on jdoodle.com.

Input :

```
System.out.println("Please work\bor I will cry");
```

Output :

```
Please work∙or I will cry
```

Why is the \b function not working, is it just due to jdoodle.com?

Comment: works fine in Java and Groovy. It is probably the method used in the website to print, escape..